# How to fix the '1' error in my restaurant.dtd.xml file?

Tags: html, css, xml, dtd, web-development-server

XML error

Could you please tell me why this file gives error?

restaurant.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="restaurant.css"?>
<!DOCTYPE Items SYSTEM "restaurant.dtd">
<Items>
  <Item Number="1">
  <Food>Hamburger</Food>
  <Price currency="USD">5.75</Price>
</Item>
  <Item Number="2">
  <Food>HotDog</Food>
  <Price currency="USD">3.50</Price>
</Item>
  <Item Number="3">
  <Food>Cola Drink</Food>
  <Price currency="USD">2.25</Price>
</Item>
</Items>
```

restaurant.dtd

```
<!ELEMENT Items (Item+)>
<!ELEMENT Item (Food, Price)>
<!ATTLIST Item Number CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT Food (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Price (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST Price currency (USD|INR) CDATA "USD">
```

I get error at the line, `<!DOCTYPE Items SYSTEM "restaurant.dtd">` stating that There is '1' error in 'restaurant.dtd'.xml

Comment: Does it help if you prepend `<!DOCTYPE Items [` and append `]>` to the DTD file, as shown in [XML DTD](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_dtd.asp)?

Answer (score 0):

The error here is really defined as
"XML Production Error: Character 'C' does not fulfill production "AttValue".

However if you change your "Price currency" ATTLIST and remove the CDATA it should work.

So, basically:

```
<!ATTLIST Price currency (USD|INR) "USD">
```

Instead of

```
<!ATTLIST Price currency (USD|INR) CDATA "USD">
```

CDATA shouldn't be neccessary in this case either way since neither "USD" or "INR" contains anything that could be interpreted as part of the XML structure.